# Re write case statement in Where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to re write the following sql server case statement used in where clause. This causes performance degradation.

```
   SELECT mode,m_name from mst_mode a 
   WHERE
       CASE @mode
          WHEN 'K' THEN 'Y'
                   ELSE ISNULL(a.MODE, 'N')
          END = CASE @mode
                   WHEN 'K' THEN 'Y'
                            ELSE @mode
   END
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

```
SELECT mode,
       m_name
FROM   mst_mode a
WHERE  ( @mode = 'K' )
        OR ( @mode <> 'K' and Isnull(a.MODE, 'N') = @mode )
```

Comment: I think the last part of the "OR" should have the ISNULL(a.mode, 'N') to also match null values in MODE.